# getting sum of value using group by

Tags: mysql

I am having a table t2. I need the sum of `vqty` group by `from_br` and `to_br` as two columns. My table is given below.
My Database schema is in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af0973/1).

t1:

```
id    branch_name
-------------------
1     branch1
2     branch2
3     branch3
4     branch4
5     branch5
6     branch6
```

t2:

```
id    from_br    to_br     qty
--------------------------------
1     1         3          10
2     2         4          20
3     3         2          30
4     2         3          40
5     1         4          50 
6     4         5          60
```

Expecting Result:

```
branch_name    send        received
-------------------------------
branch1        60          0          
branch2        60          30
branch3        30          50
branch4        60          70
branch5        0           60
```

Query I have tried is:

```
SELECT t1.branch_name, 
   COALESCE(SUM(send.vqty), 0) AS send, 
   COALESCE(SUM(receive.vqty), 0) AS received 
FROM t1  
LEFT JOIN t2 AS send on t1.id = send.from_br  
LEFT JOIN t2 AS receive on t1.id = receive.to_br 
GROUP BY t1.branch_name, send.from_br, receive.from_br
```

Comment: Your adapted [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af0973/6)

Comment: @trincot thanks, but please see my expecting result in the question it is different.

Comment: Indeed, check [this one](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af0973/26)

Comment: @trincot brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

i thank below may help you

```
 SELECT t.branch_name,  COALESCE(SUM(t.send), 0) AS send, 
    COALESCE(SUM(received), 0) AS received  from  (SELECT t1.branch_name, 
           COALESCE(SUM(send.vqty), 0) AS send, 
           COALESCE(SUM(receive.vqty), 0) AS received 
        FROM t1  
        LEFT JOIN t2 AS send on t1.id = send.from_br  
        LEFT JOIN t2 AS receive on t1.id = receive.to_br 
        GROUP BY t1.branch_name, send.from_br, receive.from_br) as t 
        GROUP BY t.branch_name
```

check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af0973/7